# How to place % and value in a single input field

Tags: html, css

I have a input field text box that has % aligned towards left and value aligned towards right and the input box is disabled. How can I achieve this using HTML and css. It should look something like the attached image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g08ZJ.png)
I have tried the below code.

```
<div>
      <input disabled class="averagePrice" [value]="3.99" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-icons"> 
  <i class="icon"> % </i> 
  <input disabled class="input-field" type="text" value="33.6"> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.input-icons i { 
  position: absolute; 
}           
.input-icons { 
  width: 100%; 
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
} 
.icon { 
  padding: 10px; 
  color: green; 
  min-width: 20px; 
  text-align: center; 
} 

.input-field { 
  padding: 10px; 
  text-align: right; 
}
```

Comment: Pleasure is all mine Dear :) Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I tried something close to what you mentioned in the image description.
Well, this can be done using the 'span' tag. A similar thing could've been achieved using the 'div' tag but when it comes to grouping elements for styling purposes, 'span' tag should be used (inline tag being more preferable than the block-level tag, in some specific cases like these).

```css
.percentinput {
    border: 1px inset #ccc;
  }
.percentinput input {
    text-align: right;
    border: 0;
  }
```

```html
<span class="percentinput">%<input disabled type="text" placeholder="33.6" ></span>
```

Comment: upvoting for being able to work with lesser code and style